# tesseract image to only digits/numbers

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tesseract, digits

Yes I know there is a lot of question for this subject but I can't find a solution.

I use `python 3.8`, `tesseract v5.0`

In this web site , there is a `captcha` image

https://medeczane.sgk.gov.tr/eczane/SayiUretenImageYeniServlet

(it changes everytick)

I download an image to try as `example.jpeg`

I try to change for example,

```
config="digits" ,config="tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"
```

then I try what I find in web. `example.jpy` is `448301`.

I want image to digit numbers and integer type. How can I do that?

`numbers = 4 ON\n\x0c`

[image]

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

numbers=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('example.jpg'),config="digits")
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: example image is= 448301 my codes result is = 4 ON\n\x0c.  i can't do it correctly

Comment: You do understand, I hope, that these Captcha images are intentionally designed to foil the common OCR algorithms.  That is their entire raison d'etre.

Comment: There are services you can subscribe to where you send your captcha image to a web service, and they send it out to a farm of human beings who read the image and respond for you.  I find that distasteful, but they do exist.

Comment: `Captcha` is for stoping people like you :) And it seems it works on this page. You may need to learn much to write more poweful program to detect numbers on images - it may need to learn a lot about `machine learning`, `neural network`, `computer vision`, etc. Start at tesseract doc: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)